# cancancan Abilities with has_and_belongs_to_many

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cancan, cancancan

I have the following relationship between my classes user and page.

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_and_belongs_to_many :pages
end

class Page < ApplicationRecord
  has_and_belongs_to_many :users
end
```

How can I do in my Ability file for a user to only edit the pages that belong to him?

```
class Ability
  include CanCan::Ability
  def initialize(user)
      if user.is? :page_administrator
        can :manage, Page
      end
  end
end
```

I try the following, but I still can not.

```
  can :manage, Page, users: { user_id: user.id }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The biggest con with `has_and_belongs_to_many` is that it makes it impossible to attach data to the join table. Instead use a join model:

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :user_pages
  has_many :pages, through: :user_pages
end

class Page < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :user_pages
  has_many :users, through: :user_pages
end

class UserPage < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :page
end
```

This works like `has_and_belongs_to_many` except its not headless - you can query `UserPage` directly. The only thing you need to do besides creating the UserPage model is renaming the table from `users_pages` to `user_pages` (or `pages_users` to `page_users`).

```
class RenameUsersPages < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.0]
  def change
    rename_table('users_pages', 'user_pages')
  end
end
```

This is needed since rails will link the table to the constant `Users::Page` otherwise.

Now you can easily attach a `admin` flag on the `UserPage` table.

```
class AddPageAdministratorToUserPages < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.0]
  change_table :users do |t|
    t.boolean :admin, default: false
   end
end
```

Now we can check if a user is an admin by checking if a record exists in `user_pages`:

```
class Ability
  include CanCan::Ability
  def initialize(user)
      can :manage, Page do |p|
        p.user_pages.exists?(admin: true, user: user)
      end
  end
end
```

Comment: You may want to check out the [rolify gem](https://github.com/RolifyCommunity/rolify) which provides a framework for role based authorization across many classes.